# Does itemChange respond to a coded change?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, selecteditemchanged

Assuming that it has been enabled, will itemChange be called if the change is induced by the program itself via, for example, a setPos?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemChange-enum), yes, the `itemChange()` function will be called after `setPos()` function call:

> [..] as the setPos() function will again call
>   itemChange(ItemPositionChange).